# bitcoin-qt -testnet wallet dumped error EXCEPTION: NSt8ios_base7failureB5cxx11E

Tags: wallet, testnet

I got an error message but don't understand what to do now, to fix this.

```
************************
EXCEPTION: NSt8ios_base7failureB5cxx11E       
CDataStream::read(): end of data: iostream error       
bitcoin in opencon       

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ios_base::failure[abi:cxx11]'
  what():  CDataStream::read(): end of data: iostream error
Aborted (core dumped)
```

My regtest and signet are doing fine. It's only wallet testnet v3.

I hope somebody can point out what it is and how to fix it.

Comment: what does this iostream error mean? anybody ?

Comment: I'm not a specialist in these things but to me smells like some lib is broken. If you try this on a brand new install of a stable version of mainstream distribution, I would sort of doubt that this kind of bug would be going to happen.

Comment: thank you i fixed it by making an clean install thank you for your responce .